# grep only get lines matching string pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I'm using grep to get lines from different files with string "[error][critical]" like `grep -r "[error][critical]" .` but it's also printing lines with "[error][warning]"

```
[error][critical] this is imp
[error][warning] ignore this
```

Not sure why is it printing lines matching [warning]

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Add option `-F` with GNU grep?

Comment: Square brackets need to be escaped  to match a literal square bracket or you'll be matching lines with any two char strings of the crossproduct (e r o) x (w a r n i g)

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to understand that square brackets have a special meaning in `grep`: `grep [0-5] test.txt` is not looking for a line, containing any number from 0 up to 5.

In the same way is `grep [error][critical] test.txt` not looking for `[error][critical]`, but it is looking for every line, containing an entry with an 'e', an 'o' or an 'r', followed by a 'c', an 'r', and 'i', a 't', an 'a' or an 'l'. You can see this clearly in the following screenshot:

[image]

The switch `-a --color=auto` highlights the `grep` results, showing the found results. From there you can easily see that your `grep` is not doing at all what you expect.

In order to solve this (in order not to have `grep` using square brackets as wildcard characters), you can use the `-F` (fixed) switch, as proposed by [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus):

[image]